# Finding Dates in one array based on the ranges from another array and closest value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, datetime

I have two Nested NumPy arrays (`dateValArr` & `searchDates`). `dateValArr` contains all dates for May 2011 (1st - 31st) and an associated value each date. `searchDates` contains 2 dates and an associated value as well (2 dates correspond to a date range).

Using date ranges specified in `searchDates` Array, I want to find dates in `dateValArr` array. Next for those selected dates in `dateValArr`, I want to find the closest value to the specified value of `searchDates`.

I have come up with is code but for the first part it it only works if only one value is specified.

```
#setup arrays ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Generate dates
st_date = '2011-05-01'
ed_date = '2011-05-31'
dates = pd.date_range(st_date,ed_date).to_numpy(dtype = object)

# Generate Values
val_arr = np.random.uniform(1,12,31)
dateValLs = []
for i,j in zip(dates,val_arr):
   dateValLs.append((i,j))

dateValArr = np.asarray(dateValLs)

print(dateValArr)    
#out:
[[Timestamp('2011-05-01 00:00:00', freq='D') 7.667399233149668]
[Timestamp('2011-05-02 00:00:00', freq='D') 5.906099813052642]
[Timestamp('2011-05-03 00:00:00', freq='D') 3.254485533826182]
...]

#Generate search dates
searchDates = np.array([(datetime(2011,5,11),datetime(2011,5,20),9),(datetime(2011,5,25),datetime(2011,5,29),2)]) 

 print(searchDates)
 #out:
[[datetime.datetime(2011, 5, 11, 0, 0) datetime.datetime(2011, 5, 20, 0, 0) 9]  
[datetime.datetime(2011, 5, 25, 0, 0) datetime.datetime(2011, 5, 29, 0, 0) 2]]

#end setup ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

x = np.where(np.logical_and(dateValArr[:,0] > searchDates[0][0], dateValArr[:,0] < search_dates[0][1]))

print(x)
out: (array([11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18], dtype=int64),)
```

However, the code works only if I select the first element `searchDates (searchDates[0][0])`. It will not run for all values in searcDates. What I mean if I replace by the following code.

```
 x = np.where(np.logical_and(dateValArr[:,0] > searchDates[0], dateValArr[:,0] < search_dates[0]))
```

Then, I will get the following error: `operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (31,) (3,)`

To find the closest value I hoping to somehow combine the following line of the code,

```
 n = (np.abs(dateValArr[:,1]-searchDates[:,2])).argmin()
```

Any ideas on how to solve it.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Only thing came into my mind is a `for loop`.

Here is the [link for my work](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1sGnNmjVSyBsOpsYH8OuZpWztMoxPEyIW)

```py
result = np.array([])
for search_term in searchDates:
  mask = (dateValArr[:,0] > search_term[0]) & (dateValArr[:,0] < search_term[1])
  date_search_result = dateValArr[mask, :]
  d = np.abs(date_search_result[:,1] - searchDates[0,2])
  result = np.hstack([result, date_search_result[d.argmin()]])
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I kinda figured out it as well,

```
 date_value = []
for i in search_dates:
    dateidx_arr = np.where(np.logical_and(dateValArr[:,0] >= i[0],dateValArr[:,0] <= i[1] )) #Get index of specified date ranges
    date_arr = dateValArr[dateidx_arr] #Based on the index get the dates and values 
    value_arr = (np.abs(date_arr[:,1]-i[2])).argmin() #for those dates calculate the closest value index
    date_value.append(date_arr[value_arr]) #Use the index to get the closest date and value
```